# Codeigniter 3 + Restserver always performs get request

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, http, codeigniter-restserver

I am using ***Codeigniter 3.1.0***, ***Restserver*** downloaded from [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) with ***documentation*** from [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814). I am also using Chrome's extension ***Postman***.

The problem is that even if i choose POST from the drop down menu of Postman, it hits the get method...
Below is the code:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Example extends REST_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function users_get() {
        echo "get request";
    }
    public function users_post() {
        echo "post request";
    }
}
```

Now through Postman, if i choose *GET* to the URL *example-domain.com/api/example/users* the preview is **get request**

If i choose *POST* to the same URL *example-domain.com/api/example/users* the preview is again **get request** and not **post request**

I didn't change anything in ***config/rest.php*** and i am using the implemented example of the Restserver in ***controllers/api/example***

Does anyone know why i can't hit the POST method?

Comment: that's strange it should automatically do the routeing to the specific post handler

Comment: exactly... and this is not my first time using CI + Restserver... that's totally weird...

Comment: try to do a clean installation of codeigniter and integrate the library

Comment: this is a clean installation

Comment: enable debug in config then try to figure out where is the problem

Comment: set $config['log_threshold']  to 4

Comment: At last found what the problem was, but still can't understand why it causes this issue. I had installed a certificate for this installation and had in .htaccess this line **RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]** to force https. But i was trying to access the API URL with HTTP and not HTTPS! What i understand is that the Rewrite Rule performs a GET redirection to HTTPS, but i'm not really sure. Can you please explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: Firstly put an answer on how you did manage to dolce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found what caused the issue. I had previously installed SSL on this domain but i was trying to call the API with HTTP.

In .htaccess i had the rewriterule

> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

to force HTTPS.

If i make a POST request with HTTPS it works like a charm.

If i make a POST request with HTTP it redirects to HTTPS (because of the rewrite rule), therefore there is a new GET request to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# CodeIgniter URL Rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```